# Unable to access an interface method from Generic that implements it

Tags: java, generics

I have a class  with generic that extends an interface. It is defined as follows -

```
Interface AnInterface {
    Result doOperation();
}


abstract class TopClass<T extends AnInterface> implements AnotherInterface<T> {

    public void concreteMethod() {
        //compiler complains for the call below. Unable to access T's method
        Result result = T.doOperation()
        // more operations on result
    }
}
```

I am not able to call interface method on T even though I have declared it to extend the interface. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: You'll need an instance of `T` to call the method on.

Answer (score 1):

`T` is a **type variable**. It's local a normal variable, except, normal variables refer to *objects*, but this is a *type variable*, so it refers to *types*.

`T.doOperation()` is therefore kinda equivalent to `String.doOperation()`.

`doOperation()` is not static, it needs to be invoked an instance. YOu are not doing that. That is why you can't - it makes no sense. Same reason you can't invoke `String.toLowerCase()` - you'd have to invoke `"someActualString".toLowerCase()`.

Comment: yes that makes sense. here each implementation of `AnInterface ` will have its own implementation of `doOperation`, which I want to call in `concreteMethod ` .  So I will have to initialize an object of `T` right? or is there a way to have a method declared static in interface and all implementing classes have it static?

Comment: static methods live entirely outside the type system, it is not possible to say that 'all subtypes of X must have this static method', therefore the entire concept that you want is dead on arrival. static methods simply do not work that way and are not dynamic in any fashion whatsoever.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is the factory pattern or some such. Instead of passing a 'T' which has the property that the type, itself, has some static method (because java does not support that as a concept), make a separate interface, these usually end in 'Factory'.